# Is it possible to block a double check?

Tags: check, double-check

Is it possible to block a double-check, or is your only option to move the king? (I'm trying to code a chess game, to then go on to code a chess AI, and this would really help me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the king is the only way to escape a double check.  There is no possible other move that will block both checks.